# CakePHP 3: saving hasOne association ($_accessible not set)

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have read several Stack Overflow posts and the documentation pages about saving associated data in CakePHP 3, but I can't get my code to work. When creating a new `Organisation`, I also want to save the data of the new account (`NewAccount`) that belongs to that `Organisation`.

Below is a reproducible part of my code. The validation of the Organisations model are executed and if passed, the data is saved. The `NewAccounts` data does not get saved, and is not even being validated. I have already checked the naming conventions in all of these files, but I can't find anything that might be a problem anymore.

```php
// Model/Table/OrganisationsTable.php
class OrganisationsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->hasOne('NewAccounts');
    }
}

// Model/Table/NewAccountsTable.php
class NewAccountsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsTo('Organisations', [
            'foreignKey' => 'organisation_id'
        ]);
    }
}

// Template/Organisations/admin_add.ctp
echo $this->Form->create($organisation);
echo $this->Form->control('new_account.email', [
    'label' => __('Email address'),
    'class' => 'form-control',
]);
echo $this->Form->control('new_account.name', [
    'label' => __('Name'),
    'class' => 'form-control',
]);
echo $this->Form->control('name', [
    'label' => __('Organisation name'),
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'class' => 'form-control',
]);

// Controller/OrganisationsController.php
class OrganisationsController extends AppController
{
    public function adminAdd() {
        $organisation = $this->Organisations->newEntity();

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Organisations->patchEntity($organisation, $this->request->getData(), [
                'associated' => ['NewAccounts']
            ]);
            if ($this->Organisations->save($organisation)) {
                $id = $organisation->id;
                debug("Success!");
            }
            else {
                debug("Error");
            }
        }

        $this->set(compact('organisation'));
    }
}
```

CakePHP documentation I have referenced:

- [Saving Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html)
- [Form](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html)
- [Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/associations.html)
- [Validating Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/validation.html)
- [Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html)

Comment: Is `new_account` "accessible" in the Organization entity?

Comment: Nope, it was not. Thanks for solving it Greg!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to make `$organisation->new_account` accessible:

```php
// Model/Entity/Organisation.php
class Organisation extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        // ...
        'new_account' => true,
    ];
}
```

By doing this, the field is marked as to be safely assigned.

[Entities: Mass Assignment (book)](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment) and [EntityTrait::$_accessible (API docs)](https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/trait-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#$_accessible)